# Neo4j indexing - what should I index to speed up a CSV load?

Tags: neo4j

I'm importing around 6m nodes with a single label from a CSV file. The Neo4J Web UI recommends creating an index to speed this up, but I'm not sure what to index. The nodes each have 5 properties - one is unique, so I've already gone ahead and indexed that field, but is it worth indexing others?

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///impressions.csv" AS row
MERGE (i:Impression { id: row._id, advertId: row.advertId, contentId: 
row.contentId, deviceId: row.deviceId });
```

The data is originally from Mongo, so the id field is a guaranteed unique.

Comment: Can you give us your cypher load csv query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re

You should create a unique constraint on field id for label Impression : `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Impression) ASSERTS n.id IS UNIQUE`

And you should also change your query by this one :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///impressions.csv" AS row
MERGE (i:Impression { id: row._id,})
  ON CREATE SET i.advertId=row.advertId, i.contentId=
row.contentId, i.deviceId=row.deviceId
```

Cheers

Comment: Aha so create with only the index field, and then set the additional fields later. That makes sense, thank you!

Comment: This loads a node & it's node properties. This can be expanded to include edgelist: source, edge weight, target node?

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing and you know that the nodes being imported don't yet exist, and that the ids for each don't exist for that label (such as if there are no :Impression nodes to start with), it may be a bit faster to leave off the constraint until after the import, and use CREATE instead of MERGE (with all properties). After the import is done, then you can create the unique constraint.

An index (including the one from a unique constraint) makes it much faster for lookups, such as MATCHes and the match part of a MERGE, but it can have an impact when writing data, as the index has to be updated, and the unique constraint tested with node creation. So if you're bulk-loading and you're absolutely certain these are all new nodes, with no duplicates on the unique property, go with an approach that makes your writes fast, then add your unique constraint after.